# Portuguese characters (like ã, ó) is read as '?' from database when I upgrade to ojdbc8.jar. It is working correctly with ojdbc6.jar. Using JBoss7.0

Tags: java, jboss, ojdbc

Ojdbc6 jar with JBoss7 works fine while fetching Portuguese characters (like ã, ó) from database using createNativeQuery. But when I upgrade to ojdbc8 jar, it doesn't work - it returns as '?' from the database. Any idea why?

Comment: Driver version, database version, database character set and national character set? Are the values stored as char or nchar values? Code sample including how you are displaying the characters.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include orai18n.jar in your classpath.